# Can we have managed Elastic search cloud in our own AWS VPC

Tags: elasticsearch

Can we use managed elastic search cloud but the data and instances in our own AWS VPC (own data center). If yes, can we have such reference in Elastic Search documentation. I have not found any details.

Comment: Are you looking for [AWS PrivateLink traffic filters](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud/current/ec-traffic-filtering-vpc.html)?

Comment: This is a way to connect to connect our VPC(private subnet resources) with elastic search provider VPC, which is different case. I want to host elastic search within my VPC as elastic cloud managed service

Comment: The only way I see is to install either [Elastic Cloud Enterprise](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud-enterprise/current/index.html) or [Elastic Cloud on Kubernetes](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud-on-k8s/current/index.html) in your own VPC.

Comment: Thanks @Val, But are these managed service ?. If yes then how can we access them. for example in normal scenario there is a link and UI to create elastic cloud. Also how it will be charged? I mean to say managed licensing cost?

Answer (score 0):

you can see OpenSearch (https://console.amazonaws.cn/aos/home?region=cn-north-1#opensearch/domains), select Elasticsearch

Comment: Not able to see any such options. I would like  to use Elastic company ES Cloud service , but VPC should be something that we can assign